Bootstrap 5 popover in responsive JS DataTable not working properly
I am building a hobby web-page using Bootstrap 5.3.3 and JS DataTables 2.0.5. On the page, I have a table with some players data. In the table i made it so when clicking on some cells a popover is shown with extra info. All the required modules are there and popover is working fine when table is shown at full width. However, if i adjust screen size so some of the columns become collapsed, the popover is not showing for those columns.
Repro example in JS Fiddle:
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Responsive Table Popover</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.2/css/responsive.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="players-data" class="table table-striped" style="font-size:13px; width: 100%;">
        <thead style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <tr>
                <th>Player</th>
                <th>Details 1</th>
                <th>Details 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
    <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.5/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.2/js/responsive.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let players = [
        {player: 'Best', details_1: 'Cool', details_2: 'Sharp', details_1_extra: 'Extra Cool', details_2_extra: 'Extra Sharp'},
        {player: 'Worst', details_1: 'Hot', details_2: 'Slow', details_1_extra: 'Extra Hot', details_2_extra: 'Extra Slow'}
      ];

      $('#players-data').DataTable({
        data: players,
        columns: [
            {data: 'player', render: DataTable.render.text(), sortable: true},
            {data: 'details_1', sortable: false, class: "text-center", render: function (data, type, row) {
                if (data)
                {
                    return `<a 
                        tabindex="0" 
                        type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-link btn-sm" 
                        data-bs-container="body" 
                        data-bs-trigger="focus" 
                        data-bs-toggle="popover" 
                        data-bs-placement="bottom" 
                        data-bs-html="true" 
                        data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover"
                        data-bs-content="${row.details_1_extra}">
                        ${data}
                    </a>`;
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }},
            {data: 'details_2', sortable: false, class: "text-center", render: function (data, type, row) {
                if (data)
                {
                    return `<a 
                        tabindex="0" 
                        type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-link btn-sm" 
                        data-bs-container="body" 
                        data-bs-trigger="focus" 
                        data-bs-toggle="popover" 
                        data-bs-placement="bottom" 
                        data-bs-html="true" 
                        data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" 
                        data-bs-content="${row.details_2_extra}">
                        ${data}
                    </a>`;
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }}
        ],
        destroy: true,
        searching: false, 
        paging: true, 
        info: false,
        ordering: true,
        stateSave: true,
        responsive: true,
        drawCallback: function (settings) {
            const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]');
            const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl));
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>

When table is full width (all columns are shown) popovers on both columns are working fine:

When "Details 2" column is collaplsed due to screen size, popover is no longer shown on it no matter if you click on cell text:

What am I missing here in my code to make popovers work no matter what?

When datatable is resized, and when uncollapsing collapsed cells, datatable actually adds another row, which contains collapsed cells, but in ul/li/span element, i.e. it creates new DOM elements, which don't have popover or any other listener attached.
example of newly added elements:


<tr data-dt-row="1" class="child">
  <td class="child" colspan="1">
    <ul data-dtr-index="1" class="dtr-details">
      <li class=" text-center" data-dtr-index="1" data-dt-row="1" data-dt-column="1">
        <span class="dtr-title">Details 1</span> <span class="dtr-data"><a tabindex="0" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-content="Extra Hot">
                        Hot
                    </a></span></li>
      <li class=" text-center" data-dtr-index="2" data-dt-row="1" data-dt-column="2"><span class="dtr-title">Details 2</span> <span class="dtr-data"><a tabindex="0" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-content="Extra Slow">
                        Slow
                    </a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>



So, what you need to do is when uncollapsing hidden cells, i.e. when datatable adds those elements, find and initiate popover on those newly added elements.
This could be done by adding separate listener on the whole table, or more precisely on collapsing element which has .dtr-control class, and then, find newly added row (which is control's parent's next sibling with class .child), and in it find all newly added popovers, and initiate them:
$('#players-data').on('click', 'td.dtr-control',  function (evt) {

const popovers = $(this).parent().next('.child').find('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
.each((i,el)=>new bootstrap.Popover(el));

});

demo:


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Responsive Table Popover</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.2/css/responsive.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="players-data" class="table table-striped" style="font-size:13px; width: 100%;">
      <thead style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <tr>
          <th>Player</th>
          <th>Details 1</th>
          <th>Details 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.5/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
  <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/3.0.2/js/responsive.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let players = [{
        player: 'Best',
        details_1: 'Cool',
        details_2: 'Sharp',
        details_1_extra: 'Extra Cool',
        details_2_extra: 'Extra Sharp'
      },
      {
        player: 'Worst',
        details_1: 'Hot',
        details_2: 'Slow',
        details_1_extra: 'Extra Hot',
        details_2_extra: 'Extra Slow'
      }
    ];

    $('#players-data').DataTable({
      data: players,
      columns: [{
          data: 'player',
          render: DataTable.render.text(),
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          data: 'details_1',
          sortable: false,
          class: "text-center",
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            if (data) {
              return `<a 
                        tabindex="0" 
                        type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-link btn-sm" 
                        data-bs-container="body" 
                        data-bs-trigger="focus" 
                        data-bs-toggle="popover" 
                        data-bs-placement="bottom" 
                        data-bs-html="true" 
                        data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover"
                        data-bs-content="${row.details_1_extra}">
                        ${data}
                    </a>`;
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        },
        {
          data: 'details_2',
          sortable: false,
          class: "text-center",
          render: function(data, type, row) {
            if (data) {
              return `<a 
                        tabindex="0" 
                        type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-link btn-sm" 
                        data-bs-container="body" 
                        data-bs-trigger="focus" 
                        data-bs-toggle="popover" 
                        data-bs-placement="bottom" 
                        data-bs-html="true" 
                        data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" 
                        data-bs-content="${row.details_2_extra}">
                        ${data}
                    </a>`;
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      destroy: true,
      searching: false,
      paging: true,
      info: false,
      ordering: true,
      stateSave: true,
      responsive: true,
      drawCallback: function(settings) {
        const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]');
        const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl));
      }
    });


    $('#players-data').on('click', 'td.dtr-control', function(evt) {

      const popovers = $(this).parent().next('.child').find('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
        .each((i, el) => new bootstrap.Popover(el));

    });
  </script>
</body>




Cool, it works, thank you! Is there anywhere in the DataTable docs one can see it, or is it a personal experience?

well, needed to dig around the code. responsive option is documented here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/, but I'm not sure any option covers your case, and also it doesn't seem to explicitly mention that it adds new elements to the DOM, which causes any listeners to be removed, including popover instance

You should make the table element a child of a div element that has a class "table-responsive", for example:
<div class="table-responsive">
       <table id="players-data" class="table table-striped" style="font-size:13px; width: 100%;">
            <thead style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Player</th>
                    <th>Details 1</th>
                    <th>Details 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


still not working, i tried it in JS Fiddle

Try initializing the popovers with "$(document).ready(function() { })" before using them

$(document).ready(function() {const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]');
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl));
})

nope, they must be initialized in drawCallback as they are created dynamically in DataTable columns. Does not help anyways.
